# PowerShell Code for Power BI APIs in Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: api, automation, powerbi, runbook

We successfully execute the code below on a domain server using regular PowerShell. However, when we execute this PowerShell code in an Azure Automation Runbook, we get a message "**Suspended
The runbook job was attempted 3 times, but it failed each time.**"

We can't use a Service Principal since you can't execute any of the admin APIs from a Service Principal. So, we need to use a regular user account to login to the Power BI APIs.

Any ideas how to get this code working in a Runbook?

```
$UserName = 'user01@sample.com'
$User_Password = 'xx@#xsrasda!@W12'
$User_Password_Secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $User_Password -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, 

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount  -Credential $Credential
    if($SuppressErrors -eq $false) 
    {
        Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
    }

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Get -Url 'admin/reports'

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this article by Gerhard Brueckl](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2017/08/refresh-powerbi-datasets-powershell-azure-runbooks/), who shows how to use the Invoke-RestMethod to bypass the Power BI cmdlets. This is the only way I've found to get Azure runbooks to work. He provides a [working sample](http://files.gbrueckl.at/blog/Refresh-PowerBI-Dataset-using-PowerShell_7C94/PowerBI_Refresh_Runbook.ps1) as well.

Your code would look similar to this. Note, though, that you will need to create an Azure App Registration and use that client ID. There's a wizard to create that at https://dev.powerbi.com/apps.

```
       $body = @{    
            "resource" = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
            "client_id" = $clientId;
            "grant_type" = "password";
            "username" = $UserName ;
            "password" = $User_Password;
            "scope" = "openid"
        }
        $resp = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUrl -Method POST -Body $body
        
         $authHeaders =   @{
            "Content-Type" = "application/json";
            "Authorization" = $authResponse.token_type + " " + $authResponse.access_token
        } 

            Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $authHeaders "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports"
```